# Ganche-cli, mine multiple transactions into one block

Tags: web3js, transactions, ganache-cli

I am using ganache-cli and web3 to build a DAPP. As part of this project I am trying to add multiple transactions into one block but facing unusual behavior. I tried options -b and --blockTime as well. In both cases the blockchain continuously mining blocks. Can someone tell why this is happening.

Here is the command I am using to run the network

```
ganache-cli -b 1 -h 127.0.0.1 -p 7545 -m "ugly.....sustain" --db address\to\db
```